# iOS titleForHeaderInSection crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, title

The problem is that the two sections are sometimes empty, so I dont know how to prevent crash when they get empty. self.globalSections is a global NSMutableArrays stored by local two NSMutableArrays which are first and second section for my UITableView.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    if (mySearchBar.text.length > 0)
    {
        if(section == 0)
        {
            //below are if statements I have tried, but not working...
            //NSUInteger globalSectionsOne = [self.globalSections indexOfObject:[self.globalSections objectAtIndex:0]];
            //if ([[self.globalSections objectAtIndex:0]count] >=1)
            //  if (globalSectionsOne!=NSNotFound)
            //if (globalSectionsOne >= 1)

            //{
                NSLog(@"sections counts");
                NSUInteger firstSectionCount = [[self.globalSections objectAtIndex:0]count];

                NSString *firstSectionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Exact match(es)", firstSectionCount];

                return firstSectionString;
            //}
            //else {return @"";}

        }
        else if (section == 1)
        {
 //another same code, except the objectAtIndex is at 1 instead of 0.
```

Please point me in the right direction, thanks.

EDIT:

I have modified in this method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (mySearchBar.text.length > 0 && [self.globalSections count] == 2)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //return 1;
}
```

Is this allright?

Comment: Update your question with Crash Log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid repeating code in your `titleForHeaderInSection:` this way:

```
if (mySearchBar.text.length > 0)
{
    if ([self.globalSections count] > section)
    {
        int sectionCount = [[self.globalSections objectAtIndex:section] count];
        NSString *matchWord = (sectionCount == 1) ? @"match" : @"matches";
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Exact %@", sectionCount, matchWord];
    }
    else
    {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I still get compiler warning like this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Can you explain what does ? and : do in NSString *matchWord = (sectionCount == 1) ? @"match" : @"matches";?

Comment: The ?: is a [terniary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).  It's just a more compact way of assigning a value to a variable when there is an if/else condition.  When the condition in the parenthesis is true the expression evaluates to the value on the left of the colon, otherwise it evaluates to the value on the right.

Comment: I just looked at the crash log you added to your original question above.  It shows the error is coming from `MainViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, not `titleForSectionInHead:`.  Take a look at the code in your `numberOfRowsInSection:` and make sure that you are checking that the `count` of your NSMutableArray is >0 before you do any call to `objectAtIndex`.

Comment: thanks for teaching me about the term terniary operator, it is space-saving codes :) You are right, I noticed it this morning and have solved my problem. Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Never index into an array whose size you don't know. Always call `count` or ensure via contract that the array has elements before calling `objectAtIndex:`. In this case, you need to accurately represent how many non-empty sections you're going to be displaying in your implementation of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

If you're returning an accurate count of the number of arrays contained in your `globalSections` array, you'll never run into the situation described above.

Comment: so you are saying that I should write like this : if ( [self.globalSections count] >= 2) before I start off this code in titleForHeaderInSection method? ( I am not sure if count is zero-based or begins with 1 if it contains one object)

Comment: It's zero-based. And yes, you could do the check like that, and return nil if it's not true.

Comment: nevermind, I found the real problem which was not this :) Thanks for taking your time to help me.